# Implementation wps-cracker - python

Tags: python, sockets, security, wifi, wps

Last thought about implementing a simple WPS cracker in python. I think you could me, student cybersecurity,give something prompt.

Firstly, the generator needs. I know that bad implementation wps gives 10 ^ 4 + 10 ^ 3 combinations. A total of 11,000. 8 messages is sent, the wps first checks the first 4 digits then the rest (8 digit is a checksum).
With this generator does not have any problems.

I only wonder how using python can connect to the router, how can I replace it with a password etc. Use to have this module socket? maybe something else? How ever write such a tool, where to get the knowledge that I so fiercely wants to explore.

What packages are used during such exchanges. how to handle the response.

For everything in advance thanks.

Comment: What do you mean for "connect to the router"?
The interaction with the router is a job for a network interface, therefore,  the thing that you can do is interact with it with some python libreries (https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsefulModules#Networking). Anyway the router is a sort of web server and for sure it has API. You can look for public API if there are any

Comment: connect to router, its bad i know. I thinking about how build package to sent for example first 4 digit to check by router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paramiko can be the library you are looking for.

Documentation:
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/

An example:
https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/python/paramiko-ssh-part1.html

It allow you to interact directly with the router, through the SSH protocol.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks man a lot. I lookin about paramiko but in ssh i saw only user/password login option. For example. I have a pin number (WPS) 12345678 i want to switch my nettwork card to monitor mode, and send first 4 digit to router, to check it equal with wps-pin. Can you explain me this?

Comment: Ok, I have this: [link](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wpa-wifi-passwords-by-cracking-wps-pin-0132542/ ) and google search "scapy python wps". I think that's all. Thanks for a time.